# Questions about standard deviation of sample standard deviation

Tags: standard-deviation, sample

Define $X$ as the random variable of interest. We observe a sequence of $T$ realized values for $x$, $x_{1},x_{2},\ldots, x_{T}$. The sample mean is 
\begin{equation*} 
m=\hat\mu = \frac{1}{T}\sum_{i=1}^{T}x_{i}
\end{equation*}
The sample variance is defined as
\begin{equation*} 
s^{2}=\hat\sigma^{2} = \frac{1}{T-1}\sum_{i=1}^{T}(x_{i}-\hat\mu)^{2}
\end{equation*}
Suppose $x_{1},x_{2},\ldots, x_{T}$ have a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^{2}$, it has been proved that
\begin{equation*}
(T-1)\hat\sigma^{2}/\sigma^{2} \sim \chi^{2}(T-1)
\end{equation*}
If the sample size $T$ is large enough, by chi-square distribution converges to a normal distribution, then:
\begin{equation}
\hat\sigma^{2} \sim N(\sigma^{2},\sigma^{4}\frac{2}{T-1})
\end{equation}
The central limit theorem states that this distribution is only valid asymptotically. How come the result that, approximately, the sample standard deviation $\hat\sigma$ has a normal distribution with a standard error of
\begin{equation}
se(\hat\sigma)=\sigma \sqrt {\frac{1}{2T}}
\end{equation}
?
By definition of standard error, $se(\hat\sigma)=\sqrt{E[\hat
\sigma^{2}-E(\hat\sigma^{2})]^{2}}=\sqrt{E[\hat\sigma^{2}]-(E[\hat\sigma])^2}=0$
I am wondering how to get the standard error $\sigma\sqrt{\frac{1}{2T}}$? Thanks!

Comment: How do you go from a chi square distribution to a normal distribution for the estimate.  The chi square distribution depends on the normality of the data in the first place.

Comment: chi square distribution converges to normal distribution as the degree of freedom goes to infinity.

Comment: The question is essentially that given the distribution of $\hat\sigma^{2}$, is there a way to get the standard error of $\hat\sigma$?